# Grep search for a string by pattern and then find part of this string inside of another file

Tags: linux, grep

I have log file where I look for  strings like:

> tail -n 1000 -f logfile.log | grep -i "host"

and then I receive strings like these:

> host2 %host-DEREG: host c459.cf00.1105 is deregistered on E0/1:60.

Could I choose mac addresses from these strings and look for strings with these mac addresses  inside of another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no macaddress in your example

```
grep `tail -n 1000 -f logfile.log | grep -i "host" | grep -o "[a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9]\.[a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9]\.[a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9][a-f0-9]"` anotherfile
```